# In GDPR data dumps, can the backslashes in file paths please be changed to forward slashes, so they're not broken for non-Windows users?

Tags: feature-request, gdpr

(A quick note: I'm a primarily Windows user, but as an occasional Mac and Linux user, and having technical knowledge of the issue, I can see why this is a problem, and many others have raised this issue for a long time.)

When downloading a GDPR data dump, the internal directory structure of the ZIP files it gives back use backslashes (`\`), not forward slashes (`/`). This poses a problem for users of Unix-based operating systems (Linux, macOS, etc.) as they don't tend to recognize the backslash as a directory delimiter, while Windows uses it as its primary directory delimiter. This means that users who attempt to browse or extract such ZIP files on non-Windows systems [often don't see the files in the folders as they should be, but instead all flattened into just files](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344596/trying-to-download-gdpr-data-dump-results-in-oops-something-bad-happened?rq=1#comment1155992_344961). This makes browsing such archives much more difficult on such systems without [tedious workarounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344596/trying-to-download-gdpr-data-dump-results-in-oops-something-bad-happened?rq=1#comment1155996_344961).

On the other hand, if the directory delimiters used in the file were forward slashes, the file would be viewable properly on non-Windows systems. It would also **still be usable for Windows users**, as Windows recognizes forward slashes in directory structures in ZIP files.

Can the GDPR data dump file please be changed to use forward slashes instead of backslashes in its data dump output, so it's better viewable on non-Windows operating systems while not breaking anything for Windows?

An employee [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344596/trying-to-download-gdpr-data-dump-results-in-oops-something-bad-happened?rq=1#comment1155999_344961) in March 2020 that they were testing that out, but nothing has come since then (possibly due to the pandemic affecting operations at the time): see [this post from May 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364478/377214) that says it's still an issue today.

Comment: ZIP'ping folders with files/sub folders, moving the ZIP file to/from Windows/Linux, extracting on the other system, browsing the folder tree, and opening files  is normally not problem (I do it on a regular basis, in both directions). What is different here? Software? ZIP versions?